# Update bulk data with correct information using SQL

Tags: sql, database, netezza

We have been populated wrong data into NZ database and along with the fix we need to fix the history data as well.

Wrong data sample

```
ID                |from_date          |to_date
5002800000gvgQHAAY|2017-04-05 07:13:42|2017-05-04 07:27:03
5002800000gvgQHAAY|2017-04-06 06:40:08|2017-05-04 07:27:03
5002800000gvgQHAAY|2017-04-07 07:44:08|2017-05-04 07:27:03
5002800000gvgQHAAY|2017-04-08 06:00:22|2017-05-04 07:27:03
5002800000gvgQHAAY|2017-04-12 07:00:22|2017-05-04 07:27:03
5002800000gvgQHAAY|2017-04-20 11:05:20|2017-05-04 07:27:03
5002800000gvgQHAAY|2017-05-04 07:27:04|2999-12-31 00:00:00
```

Correct way to populate

```
ID                |from_date          |to_date
5002800000gvgQHAAY|2017-04-05 07:13:42|2017-04-06 06:40:08
5002800000gvgQHAAY|2017-04-06 06:40:08|2017-04-07 07:44:08
5002800000gvgQHAAY|2017-04-07 07:44:08|2017-04-08 06:00:22
5002800000gvgQHAAY|2017-04-08 06:00:22|2017-04-12 07:00:22
5002800000gvgQHAAY|2017-04-12 07:00:22|2017-04-20 11:05:20
5002800000gvgQHAAY|2017-04-20 11:05:20|2017-05-04 07:27:03
5002800000gvgQHAAY|2017-05-04 07:27:04|2999-12-31 00:00:00
```

Just wondering that we can use SQL to fix the data as above.
if someone could help on this much appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Are you looking for an Oracle solution or a Netezza solution?

Comment: I'm looking for Netezza solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to "fix" the entire table, the most efficient way to do this would be to create a new table based on this query, and then rename the old and new table once the data looked good to you:

```
select id, from_date, 
lead(from_date,1, '2999-12-31 00:00:00') over (partition by id order by from_date) to_date
from test_table order by id, from_date;
         ID         |      FROM_DATE      |       TO_DATE       
--------------------+---------------------+---------------------
 5002800000gvgQHAAY | 2017-04-05 07:13:42 | 2017-04-06 06:40:08
 5002800000gvgQHAAY | 2017-04-06 06:40:08 | 2017-04-07 07:44:08
 5002800000gvgQHAAY | 2017-04-07 07:44:08 | 2017-04-08 06:00:22
 5002800000gvgQHAAY | 2017-04-08 06:00:22 | 2017-04-12 07:00:22
 5002800000gvgQHAAY | 2017-04-12 07:00:22 | 2017-04-20 11:05:20
 5002800000gvgQHAAY | 2017-04-20 11:05:20 | 2017-05-04 07:27:04
 5002800000gvgQHAAY | 2017-05-04 07:27:04 | 2999-12-31 00:00:00
(7 rows)

create table new_test_table as
select id, from_date, 
lead(from_date,1, '2999-12-31 00:00:00') over (partition by id order by from_date) to_date
from test_table;
INSERT 0 7
```

Comment: In netezza i'm getting below error                                                            Function 'EAD' is not an analytic aggregate but is called with a window spec

Comment: Then you likely have accidentally added some whitespace between the L and the EAD of the LEAD function call  - or *I* mispasted.   Yep - I mispasted the create table command. Try it now

Comment: All good, above SQL worked perfectly, thanks a bunch ! much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in tsql (which runs on microsoft sql server).Sorry I am not familiar with netezza, and since no one is responding , I will. Anyway Tsql looks very similar to netezzas sql, so you will need to fine-tune it to work in netezza. Basically you would use some function to get the index of the rows ordered by from_date. Then try to join successive rows to transform the to_date.

```
declare @data table(
    ID varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
    from_date datetime NOT NULL,
    to_date datetime NOT NULL
)

insert into @data (ID, from_date,to_date) VALUES
('5002800000gvgQHAAY','2017-04-05 07:13:42','2017-05-04 07:27:03'),
('5002800000gvgQHAAY','2017-04-06 06:40:08','2017-05-04 07:27:03'),
('5002800000gvgQHAAY','2017-04-07 07:44:08','2017-05-04 07:27:03'),
('5002800000gvgQHAAY','2017-04-08 06:00:22','2017-05-04 07:27:03'),
('5002800000gvgQHAAY','2017-04-12 07:00:22','2017-05-04 07:27:03'),
('5002800000gvgQHAAY','2017-04-20 11:05:20','2017-05-04 07:27:03'),
('5002800000gvgQHAAY','2017-05-04 07:27:04','2999-12-31 00:00:00')

;with cte_data(ID,from_date,to_date,row_idx)
as
(
    select ID,from_date,to_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY from_date) row_idx
     from @data
)
select data1.ID,data1.from_date,
coalesce(data2.from_date,'2999-12-31 00:00:00') [to_date]
from cte_data data1
left join cte_data data2 on data2.row_idx = data1.row_idx + 1
```

Hope you find this helpful.